Bound the volume by the mean curvature of the boundary
Let $M$ be a compact compact Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature and smooth boundary $N$. Assume that the mean curvature $H_N$ of $N$ is positive.
Question: How to determine a constant $C$ such that $$\int_N \frac{1}{H_N}\geq C\cdot \mathrm{Vol}(M)$$
and the equality holds if and only if $M$ is a ball in an Euclidean space?
It seems like $C=\frac{\dim M+1}{\dim M}$, however, I failed to prove such an inequality in this case.

Let $N_r$ be the level set $\mathrm{dist}_N=r$, and $\pi_r\colon N_r\to N$ is the normal projection; it is uniquely defined almost everywhere.
Notice that the Jacobian of $\pi_r$ at $x$ can be estimated from $r$ and $H(\pi_r(x))$ with the equality case for the round ball.
Integrating you get a bound on area of $N_r$.
It remains to apply the coarea formula.
